# How to add wrapper JSON to Mutiny Multi?

Tags: java, jackson, reactive-streams, mutiny, smallrye

I have a Java method which creates the customer information in JSON format using the streams approach and returns as and when it is created in an asynchronous approach using the `Multi` from `SmallRye Mutiny`.

I would like to add the wrapper to this JSON which is being created using the `Jackson JsonGenerator`. I don't understand how to add the same. I believe I need to make use of the `Multi.createBy().concatenating()` to achieve [this](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/guides/merging-and-concatenating-streams/#merging-multis).

The following is the method that I have:

```
public static Multi<Customer> generateCustomer(final Input input) {
    try {
        return Multi.createFrom().publisher(new CustomerPublisher(input));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new NewException("Exception occurred during the generation of Customer : " + e);
    }
}
```

The above method currently returns something like this asynchronously:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Batman",
    "age":45,
    "city":"gotham"
  },
  {
    "name":"superman",
    "age":50,
    "city":"moon"
  }
]
```

I would like to add a wrapper to this JSON and create something like this:

```
{
  "isA": "customerDocument",
  "createdOn": "2022-10-10T12:29:43",
  "customerBody": {
    "customerList": [
      {
        "name": "Batman",
        "age": 45,
        "city": "gotham"
      },
      {
        "name": "superman",
        "age": 50,
        "city": "moon"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I have added a method which does this and I would like to call the same, but I am unable to append the same to my  `return Multi.createFrom().publisher`

```
public class CustomerGenerator {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream jsonOutput;
    private JsonGenerator jsonGenerator;

    private CustomerGenerator() {
        try {
            jsonOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            jsonGenerator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(jsonOutput).useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new TestDataGeneratorException("Exception occurred during the generation of customer document : " + ex);
        }
    }

    public static Multi < Customer > generateCustomer(final Input input) {
        CustomerGenerator customerGenerator = new CustomerGenerator();
        customerGenerator.wrapperStart();
        try {
            return Multi.createFrom().publisher(new CustomerPublisher(input));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NewException("Exception occurred during the generation of Customer : " + e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("ALL DONE");
            customerGenerator.wrapperEnd();
        }
    }

    public void wrapperStart() {
        try {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("type", "customerDocument");
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("creationDate", Instant.now().toString());
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("customerBody");
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("customerList");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new TestDataGeneratorException("Exception occurred during customer document wrapper creation : " + ex);
        }
    }

    public void wrapperEnd() {
        try {
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject(); // End body
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject(); // End whole json file
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new TestDataGeneratorException("Exception occurred during customer document wrapper creation : " + ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                jsonGenerator.close();
                System.out.println("JSON DOCUMENT STRING : " + jsonOutput.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had created a `jsongenerator` that creates the wrapper for your first json (not using mutiny) , this could help you ?

Comment: @dariosicily Thanks a lot for your response but I did not understand your response completely. Do you mean you have created JSON using the `JsonGenerator` which you would like to provide? I am already creating the wrapper using the `JsonGenerator` and provided the same using the question. All I need to do is append that JSON to the mutiny which is returning the response asynchronously. I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach wouldn't make as you are wrapping random input that goes out of the `CustomGenerator` control.

Since you are able to generate the final output only when all emitted `Customer` object are emitted, and supposing you would like to retain a object oriented approach (i.e. not shifting to emitting JSON tokens), you should collect the emitted customers then wrap the collected items into your final JSON output:

```
Uni<byte[]> result = Multi.createFrom().publisher(new CustomerPublisher(input))
    .collect()
    .asList()
    .map(customers -> {
        ByteArrayOutputStream jsonOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(jsonOutput).useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("type", "customerDocument");
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("creationDate", Instant.now().toString());
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("customerBody");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeArrayFieldStart("customerList");
        customers.forEach(customer -> jsonGenerator.writeObject(customer));
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        jsonGnenerator.close();
        return jsonOutput.toByteArray();
    });
```